# Creating read-only Microsoft Word file using VB.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, ms-word

I am trying to create a Microsoft Word file in VB.net which is read only.

My aim is that user will input the data in a Windows form, after pressing export button it'll get exported to a Word document.  But here's a twist: I want this Word file to be read only.
Is there any option to do this?  I have tried exporting through Crystal Report, but its still editable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like PDF may be a more fitting solution.

Comment: Thanks Steven for your reply. But my user wants it in Word doc only.

Comment: Crystal Reports will not create read-only Word documents.

Comment: Yes Craig, you are right that is the reason I am trying to create readonly word doc. do you have any soln?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `File.SetAttributes` method for that, I think. Check the [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.setattributes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Comment: I have used [File.SetAttributes] but still I am able to modify the contents in word.

Comment: You can always modify the contents in Word and save the result elsewhere, unless you have protected the document internally (e.g. "protected for forms"). And that's assuming that the user has opened the document in Word.